# Нужно заставить программу спамить кнопку

Tags: python

1) Сейчас начал работать с PyAutoGui. Мне нужна программа, которая будет просто нажимать одну кнопку c n-й частотой к моменту пока на экране не появится нужный мне значок.
2) Есть ли модуль в стандартной библиотеке Python, который может продолжить роботу функции невзирая на ошибки(если try то опишите как это сделать)?
Благодарю заранее.

Comment: Так и делайте через PyAutoGui. Если покажете код, где у вас возникают ошибки, будет проще показать, как игнорировать ошибки (или избежать их).

Comment: смотря какие ошибки